# Estimating standard error of related regressions in R

Tags: r, regression, estimation, heteroscedasticity

I am working with regressions to understand the price creation of certain future contracts for commodities and try to explain it with other commodity pricese.
These future contracts have different time periods until they start with their delivery.
It is intuitive that a future contract with a long time to delivery e.g. 1 year has a higher standard error and is harder to explain by the other prices than a contract that has only one month to delivery left.

So I have data available for 1month, 3month and 6month. I would like to know if there is in R a possibility to estimate the regression functions of 2,3, ... 12months by the parameters gained in the 3 regressions. Do you think that would be reasonable?

thanks! Best F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to infer prices of futures deliverable any time within 12 months as a function of "factors" and "delivery time". The data you have though has delivery time of only 1,3, or 6 months. This usually severely hampers results, be prepared.

Because there is going to be heteroskedasticity this is what you should do:

1. Fit your OLS $Y = \alpha X + \beta T + \epsilon$, where $Y$ is the contract price, $X$ are factors and $T$ is time (not necessarilly a linear function of it).
2. Get the residuals from your regression and square them: $\hat \epsilon ^2$
3. Now fit a **nonlinear regression** $\hat \epsilon ^2 = f(x) + f(T)$ ("gam" library in R is your friend)
4. The result of your second regression is your estimate variance. Make sure your claim was correct (that is $\hat \epsilon ^2$ increases with $T$) and discover new stuff (is any factor $X$ also affecting variance?)
5. Now go back to step 1, but this time run a [WLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares) regression, where the weights are given by the function you estimated on step 3.

Keep repeating that loop until the $\alpha$ and the $\beta$ converge somewhere. Which they usually do.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach to this would be to fit a variance function to the data using time left to delivery as a variable to explain the changing variance.